# Join exactly 1 record even if on condition match multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql, join

**Sample Query**

```
SELECT count(A.ID) 
FROM `TABLE_A` A LEFT JOIN `TABLE_B` B ON (A.ID=B.ID) 
WHERE .....
```

I need:

Even if `A.id`  match multiple records in Table B it should be consider as only one.

**Actual Query**

```
SELECT CampaignName,fsbcorponline.leads360campaigns.CostPerLead, 
count(fsbcorponline.leads360leads.id) leadCount,
count(CASE WHEN fsbcorponline.leads360leads.leadStatus like '%Contact Attempt%' OR                                
leadStatus like '%Call Back/Follow-up%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Working%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Credit Pulled%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Selected other Lender%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Pre-Approved%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Application Taken/Sent%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Application Received%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Submitted%' OR                                
leadStatus like '%Funded%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Future Opportunity%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Manager Review%' THEN 1 END ) leadContacted,         
COUNT(CASE WHEN fsbcorponline.leads360leads.lead_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END ) leadsToEncompass ,          
COUNT(CASE WHEN fsbcorponline.leads_to_loan.loan_closeDate IS NOT NULL AND loan_closeDate !='1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 END ) leadsToEncompassClose,         
COUNT(CASE WHEN fsbcorponline.leads_to_loan.loan_FundedDate IS NOT NULL AND loan_FundedDate !='1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 END ) leadsToEncompassFunded  
FROM (fsbcorponline.leads360leads LEFT JOIN fsbcorponline.leads360campaigns ON fsbcorponline.leads360leads.CampaignId=fsbcorponline.leads360campaigns.CampaignId)  
LEFT JOIN fsbcorponline.leads_to_loan ON fsbcorponline.leads360leads.id =lead_id  
Where 1=1 AND dateAdded between '11/24/2012 08:59:00' and '12/24/2012 08:59:00'AND CampaignName like '%TFSB.com%'
```

Comment: But if you remove the extra rows, why do you need the left join in the first place? If you do (distinct A.ID), any WHERE condition on B (or even removing the join on B) is not going to affect the result returned.

Comment: please see the Actual query added.

Comment: @Champ: Edit your query and specify which columns in the SELECT clause come from what table.

Answer (score 2):

try this `distinct count` will do,

```
SELECT count(distinct A.ID) 
FROM `TABLE_A` A JOIN `TABLE_B` B ON (A.ID=B.ID) 
WHERE .....
```

Since you are concerned about 
only matching records, simply `JOIN` will do and no need of `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT CampaignName,fsbcorponline.leads360campaigns.CostPerLead, 
count( distinct fsbcorponline.leads360leads.id) leadCount,
count(
CASE WHEN leadStatus like '%Contact Attempt%' OR                                
leadStatus like '%Call Back/Follow-up%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Working%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Credit Pulled%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Selected other Lender%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Pre-Approved%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Application Taken/Sent%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Application Received%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Submitted%' OR                                
leadStatus like '%Funded%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Future Opportunity%' OR                                 
leadStatus like '%Manager Review%' THEN 1 END ) leadContacted,         
COUNT
(CASE WHEN lead_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END ) leadsToEncompass ,          
COUNT(CASE WHEN loan_closeDate IS NOT NULL AND loan_closeDate !='1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 END ) leadsToEncompassClose,         
COUNT(CASE WHEN loan_FundedDate IS NOT NULL AND loan_FundedDate !='1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 END ) leadsToEncompassFunded  
FROM (fsbcorponline.leads360leads LEFT JOIN fsbcorponline.leads360campaigns ON fsbcorponline.leads360leads.CampaignId=fsbcorponline.leads360campaigns.CampaignId)  
LEFT JOIN fsbcorponline.leads_to_loan ON fsbcorponline.leads360leads.id =lead_id  
Where 1=1 AND dateAdded between '11/24/2012 08:59:00' and '12/24/2012 08:59:00'AND CampaignName like '%TFSB.com%'
```

Comment: please see the Actual query added.

Comment: @Champ try this and let me know what are you getting

Comment: that is giving me the correct count of `fsbcorponline.leads360leads.id` because of distinct. i cant add `distinct` on the fields like  `leadStatus ` etc... so the question remains the same how to restrict join to match adjectly one row

Answer (score 2):

A `GROUP BY` clause can be used for this purpose:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.ID) 
FROM `TABLE_A` A LEFT JOIN `TABLE_B` B ON (A.ID=B.ID) 
WHERE .....
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Comment: please see the Actual query added.